# cannot resolve symbol textview in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android

[image]

here mtv is TextView. and i get a error cannot resolve symbol mtv

Comment: PLease post your code

Comment: added protected or public field to it

Comment: We need your code to find out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: please check "ENTER IMAGE DESCRIPTION HERE" http://i.stack.imgur.com/7miQX.png

Comment: Make sure you have created object for holder to access it items.

Comment: Typically it is better to post code as text using the tools in the WYSIWYG editor provided. Adding your code through an image is not the best way to accomplish this task.

Comment: add access specifier will solve the error i think.. Try adding protected TextView mtv;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first parameter from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to `RecyclerView.ViewHolderRec` in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Comment: Thank you @Zahidul Islam

Answer (score 0):

ViewHolder:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}
```

RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

}
```

Comment: That surprise me since it is the example code of the official Android Training tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html